# Does `deflate` always compress your entire block?

Tags: java, compression, gzip, deflate

Here's example from the documentation:

```
 byte[] output = new byte[100];
 Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
 compresser.setInput(input);
 compresser.finish();
 int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);
 compresser.end();
```

but `DeflaterOutputStream` does this:

```
        if (!def.finished()) {
            def.setInput(b, off, len);
            while (!def.needsInput()) {
                 int len = def.deflate(buf, 0, buf.length);
                 if (len > 0) {
                 out.write(buf, 0, len);
               }
            }
        }
```

which makes me think that just because you've gotten a non-zero return from a call to `deflate()` does not mean that your entire input was compressed.

Is this correct? In the documentation, I'm having trouble finding where this is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: There might not be room in the buffer to compress the entire input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not have finished if you didn't give it enough output space. You need to keep calling `deflate()` with more output space until `finished()` is true.

Note that it will never report that it finished if you didn't tell it that you have provided all of the input with `finish()`. Which the example does.

Comment: So if you call `finish()` before, then `needsInput() == finished()` and if you don't call `finish()`, then you can add more data input to be a part of the same "block"?

Comment: Yes, until you call `finish()`, you can keep providing more input with `setInput()` and more output space with `deflate()`, and keep compressing forever.

Comment: I don't understand your `needsInput() == finished()`. What you could do is have an inner loop calling `deflate()` until the output buffer is not filled, and an outer loop called `setInput()` to provide more input. When that outer loop has reached the end of the input it intends to provide, it would call `finish()` before heading to the inner loop.

Comment: If you do that, it is assured (though always good to check) that after the inner loop `needsInput()` will be true, and after `finish()` has been provided, and then after the inner loop, `finished()` will be true. Exit the outer loop on `finished()`.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a single loop that keeps calling `deflate()` with more output space and doing something with the output each time, and in that loop check `needsInput()` and when true, provide more input, using `finish()` when the last of the input has been provided, before doing the `deflate()`. Exit the loop when `finished()` is true.

Comment: I'm encountering a case where I called `finish()` and despite `needsInput()` being true, we have that `!finished()`

Comment: Also, right at the location in the file I'm testing the compression on where this occurs, I end up getting a CRC error for my final `gzip` compression (I am using multiple `Deflater` objects -- one per block of data)

Comment: Your case after having called `finish()` means there is more output pending which you need to get with more `deflate()` calls. Once the output buffer is not filled to the brim, then `finished()` will be true.

Comment: You need to post a new question with your code, what is happening, and what you expected to happen instead. Comments are not the place for more questions.

Comment: For the case where `finish()` is not called. This relates to this question. If `needsInput()` is true, does that always mean that it has processed all the input you've currently given it? In particular, I'm imagining a case where there is no space available, so `deflate` gives 0, but actually you do not need more input.

Comment: If `needsInput()` is true, then yes, it has processed all of the input you have given. However `deflate()` may have not yet delivered all of the output that will result from that input.

Comment: So how can we tell if `deflate()` has done so? In particular, when we don't call `finish()`. That is the particular thing I wish to remedy.

Comment: If you don't call `finish()` then there may be data you never get out of `deflate()` until you provide more input, or until you request a flush with the `deflate()`. The compression engine collects data until it has enough for a block, and only then will it spit it out.

Comment: Even with `SYNC_FLUSH`?

Comment: I said until you request a flush.

Comment: Comments are not for questions. Questions are for questions. I'm not going to answer any more of the infinite stream of questions in the comments here.